# Gstreamer SDK on Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, gstreamer

I am new to Gstreamer and I have some problems by installing the sdk.
I followed what is wrote here: http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Windows

And this is what I done:

- I installed Visual Studio Community Edition 2015, and I created a new Empty C project. In this way I downloaded and installed Microsoft's C/C++ compiler and linker's stuffs.
- I went here http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.6.1/ and I downloaded Gstreamer Runtime and Gstreamer Sdk installers. (gstreamer-1.0-x86_64-1.6.1.msi and gstreamer-1.0-devel-x86_64-1.6.1.msi). I am on a 64bit platform.

After I installed all this, I found the folder C:\gstreamer that contains the Runtime stuffs.. I also have the environment variable GSTREAMER_1_0_ROOT_X86_64 pointing to C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\

By following the linked guide, I would find also the environment variable GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_X86_64 and the C:\gstreamer-sdk folder, but I haven't them in my computer. So what am I forgetting?

I am using Windows 7 64 bit with VS 2015.

Thank you for your patience, I searched a lot in the network before without any results.

Comment: FYI: http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Windows is related to 0.10 and not owned by the gstreamer project. What actually is not working?